# Flutter: Pass argument as type for casting

Tags: flutter

I am trying to pass 'type' as argument for casting as snippet code below.

```
function casting(a, callback, type) {
   a.map((e) => callback(e) as type).toList();
}
```

is there any way to do this? thanks.

Comment: try template function, casting<T>(a, callback), then use T to cast the result of your callback execution.

Comment: You'll probably need to go with generics, like casting<T>(a, callback) => a.map((e) => callback(e) as T);

Answer (score 0):

found the solution from [How to pass a generic type as a parameter to a Future in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56271651/how-to-pass-a-generic-type-as-a-parameter-to-a-future-in-flutter)

```
function casting<T>(a, callback) {
   a.map((e) => callback(e) as T).toList();
}
```

also thanks to @ndnam198 for fast response